# http interceptor order not taking into account

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an app with some interceptors. I declared these in this order:

- loading interceptor
- auth interceptor
- database error interceptor
- global http error interceptor

If I f.e. want to delete a record, where there are some related records, the database error interceptor catches the error and gives a meaningful notification. Here is the code:

```
intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (!(error.error instanceof ErrorEvent)) {
          const httpError = error.error as CustomHttpErrorResponse;

          if (httpError.message == 'Database error') {
            const dbError = httpError as DatabaseError;
            switch (dbError.details.code) {
              case '23503':
                this.notifyService.showNotification(
                  request.context.get(NOTIFICATION_TYPE).type,
                  5000,
                  'error',
                  'Törlés nem sikerült!',
                  `A törlés sajnos nem sikerült, mivel még vannak kapcsolódó objektumok (${this.getReferencedObjectName(
                    dbError.details.detail
                  )}).`,
                  request.context.get(NOTIFICATION_TYPE).container
                );
                break;
              case '23505':
                this.notifyService.showNotification(
                  request.context.get(NOTIFICATION_TYPE).type,
                  5000,
                  'error',
                  'Mentés nem sikerült!',
                  'A hozzáadni kívánt elem már létezik a listában.',
                  request.context.get(NOTIFICATION_TYPE).container
                );
                break;
            }
          }
        }
        return throwError(() => error);
      })
    );
  }
```

After that it should stop the interceptor chain. But for some reason, I don't get the notification, instead I get the notification from the global http error interceptor.

Here is the code of the global  http error interceptor:

```
intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (!(error.error instanceof ErrorEvent)) {
          if (error.status != 401) {
            this.notifyService.showNotification(
              request.context.get(NOTIFICATION_TYPE).type,
              5000,
              'error',
              'Hiba',
              'Ismeretlen eredetű hiba lépett fel. Lépj kapcsolatba a rendszer adminisztrátorával.',
              request.context.get(NOTIFICATION_TYPE).container
            );
            this.loaderService.hide();
            return of();
          }
        }
        return throwError(() => error);
      })
    );
  }
```

First, I thought, this is because in the database error interceptor I rethrow the error and the next interceptor catches it. But if I simply return an empty observable like `return of()`, the global http error interceptor is reached in this case too.

I checked it with console log (right after this line, before the `if`: `catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {`), the database error interceptor is reached, but the `catchError` codeblock not.

Why is that? What am'I overseeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interceptor order works both ways.

[image]
[Source](https://angular.io/guide/http-intercept-requests-and-responses#interceptor-order)

The first interceptor transforms the request, then the 2nd, then the 3rd.

Then the response arrives and the last interceptor callback is first to run, then the 2nd-to-last etc.

This is why your global interceptor is the first to handle the response.

Comment: Thanks. Curiously, I was aware of that, but this is a typic case, where I concentrate on one thing, and don't see the whole picture.